# How to change the connection string with database-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, npgsql

I want to change the data source address in my database first project.

This is my code:

```
string connect = "metadata=res://*/ornekDBEnt.csdl|res://*/ornekDBEnt.ssdl|res://*/ornekEnt.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;Host=127.0.0.1;Username=postgres;Password=pass1;Persist Security Info=True;Database=ornekdb&quot;";
updateConfigFile(connect);

public void updateConfigFile(string con)
{
    //updating config file
    XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    //Loading the Config file
    XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

    foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
    {
        if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
        {
            //setting the coonection string
            xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[1].Value = con;
        }
    }
    //writing the connection string in config file
    XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
}
```

I get the following error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'host'.'

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. Please also include the error you're receiving.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'host'.'

Comment: This is a format to the connection string:Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider;Data Source=myServerAddress;location=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;password=myPassword;

Comment: @Bibin not work your code

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'data source'.'